# How I can implement e.preventDefault(); in useEffect?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a question for you. I want to add e.preventDefault(); in useEffect so that it is called as soon as the state changes to true. But something does not work, can someone tell me how to implement this method.

```
const [active, setActive] = useState(false);
 useEffect((e) => {
    if (active === true) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
}, [active])



<ul
    onClick={() => setBurger(false)}
    <className="nav__ul">
    <li><Link to='/homeWork'>Таблица</Link></li>
    <li><a href="#photo__h2">Галерея</a></li>
    <li><a href="#questions__head">Питання-відповідь </a></li>
    <li><a href="#contacts__h3">Контакти</a></li>
    <li onClick={() => setActive(true)}><a href="/" className="popup_open">Забронювати</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: What default behaviour are you expecting from clicking on a list item? It's not clear what you're trying to do but I'm going to guess this isn't the solution. Maybe add more details to your question.

Comment: `e.preventDefault` must be in your `onClick` callback, not `useEffect`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have access to event instance inside useEffect. It's accessible in onClick callback not inside effect.

```
const onClick = useCallback((e) => {
  setActive(true)
  e.preventDefault()
})

...
<li onClick={onClick} ...
```

It's also generally a good idea to always wrap your callbacks using `useCallback()` - this way your callbacks won't need to be re-wired on every render - because on every render you generate new closure.

If you don't wrap your callbacks with 'useCallback()', behind the scene react will be replacing event handler on every render, similarly to:

```
element.removeEventListener('click', oldClosure)
element.addEventListener('click', newClosure)
```

also, I'm not sure but looking at your code, I think you might be wanting to put onClick on `<a>` element not on `<li>`

Comment: Ty very much, sir