# How to pass event object as second parameter to callBack function

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-hooks

I would like a callback function to also execute event.stopPropagation() on the div element where it is being called in addition to updating the state. QueryInput is the customized input div element where user can add text. I want the cursor to retain the focus in the QueryInput when tab key is pressed. Hence, will add stopPropagation() and preventDefault functions. Is it possible to pass event object as a second parameter ?
I tried passing it, but it is not being recognized.

```
const handleQueryChange = useCallback(
    (q,e) => {
      e.stopPropagation();
      e.preventDefault();
      updateModel({
        ...model,
        query: q
      });
    },
    [updateModel, model]
  );
```

The call to the callback function is being made it another file

```js
<QueryInput
  id="queryText"
  query={query || ""}
  setSearchQuery={(q, event) => handleQueryChange(q, event)}
>
```

I get **Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'stopPropagation')** error when I try to do so.
How do I pass event object as a parameter ?
Without event object, I just call the function as

```js
setSearchQuery={handleQueryChange}
```

Comment: Can you share where and how the `setSearchQuery` is implemented?

Comment: setSearchQuery basically just updates the query stored based on what is entered in the input text box. QueryInput is the customized version on input div element.

Comment: My question is: Why you must pass event as the **second** parameter?

Comment: How do I stop eventPropogation or the default tab behavior otherwise ?

Comment: can you please include what `QueryInput` looks like ?

Answer (score 1):

This is how to pass the `handleQueryChange` function to `QueryInput` as `setSearchQuery`:

```js
<QueryInput
  id="queryText"
  query={query || ""}
  setSearchQuery={handleQueryChange}
/>
```

and update it like this, the function needs only the event object and from this latter you can retrive the value of the input

```js
const handleQueryChange = useCallback(
  (e) => {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    updateModel({
      ...model,
      query: e.target.value,
    });
  },
  [updateModel, model]
)
```

Then from `QueryInput` you call it this way :

```js
const QueryInput = ({ id, query, setSearchQuery }) => {
  //...
  return (
    //...
    <input
      onChange={(event) => {
        setSearchQuery(event);
      }}
    />
  );
}
```

Comment: This is what I tried as well! But I get e as undefined.

Comment: can you include the two components or at least give the link to the project github repo

Comment: Both handleQueryChange and <input> element are in two different files. I have defined all the hooks(including handleQueryChange function) in a separate file that I import in main main Component.  Would that be the reason why event is not being recognized ?

Comment: bro why don't you include the file where lives `handleQueryChange` and the file of `QueryInput` so we can understand better whats going on and help you

Answer (score 1):

Found from https://stackoverflow.com/a/72290748/10562084

```js
const App = () => {
    const [name, setName] = React.useState('John');

    const handleQueryChange = React.useCallback((e) => {
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();
        setName(e.currentTarget.value);
      },
      [name]);

    return (
        <div>
            <h1>name: {name}</h1>
            <input placeholder='name' onChange={handleQueryChange} />
        </div>
    )
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16.7.0-alpha.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16.7.0-alpha.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, `QueryInput` is your component, it is not a native HTML element. Similarly, the `setSearchQuery` function is also defined by you. Your problem has to be fixed at the place where you are utilizing the native element's events.

e.g.,

```
<input onChange={(e)=> setSearchQuery(yourData, e)} />
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are some common patterns in vanilla JavaScript though:

```
document.addEventListener(‘click’, function(event) { callback(event, x, y) })
```

// or in arrow form and maybe a scenario where the event object isn't needed

```
document.addEventListener(‘click’, () => callback(props) )
```

In React, not vanilla JS, the above implementation can be added as an event listener using the useEffect hook (from react api) and passing in the addEventListener function as a dependency.  we first define a new function handleClick that calls callback with the props object as an argument. Then, we use the useEffect hook to add an event listener to the document object that listens for the click event and calls our handleClick function when it occurs.

The useEffect hook also returns a cleanup function that removes the event listener when the component is unmounted or when the callback or props values change, to avoid memory leaks. So you dont need to worry about target and stopPropagation etc, as its covered for you in the useEffect hook (from react api).

Note the callback at the bottom in the array with the props:

```
import { useEffect } from 'react';

function YourComponent(props) {
  useEffect(() => {
    const handleClick = () => {
      callback(props);
    };

    document.addEventListener('click', handleClick);

    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener('click', handleClick);
    };
  }, [callback, props]);

  return null; // or your component JSX
}
```